# how to check javascript syntax error

Tags: javascript, ajax, firebug

Firebug looks not capable to check js syntax error...

Is there any good way to do that?

Currently I just wrote a js but the firebug didn't show any error but the functionality is totally broken.

Comment: Firebug can do that. also _functionality is totally broken_ need  not be related to syntax errors. If you think firebug is not pointing out at a specific error, can you post a screenshot?

Comment: sometime it also happens to me, you need to enable as Sarfraz said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firebug does do it. Make sure that you have JavaScript Console enabled, you can do so by clicking the **Console** dropdown and from their select **Enabled**. You need to press <kbd>F12</kbd> key to open firebug and once you refresh the page, you will see any errors you have in your script in the firebug js console.

If you are using Firefox, you can also press <kbd>Contr+Shift+J</kbd> to open firefox's error dialog.

Answer (score 1):

are you sure Firebug is turned on? If it's on, the little bug in the lower right is colored brown. if it's not on, the bug is gray.

also, I find that Web Inspector in Safari/Chrome is better.