# Firebug Javascript syntax errors in linked external files cause file to be ignored

Tags: javascript, firebug

I'm having trouble getting **FireBug** to report certain **Javascript** syntax errors. I have seen earlier discussions on this site [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984507/how-to-check-javascript-syntax-error), and I know how to enable Javascript error checking. But if there is a **syntax** error in a **linked external script file**, FireBug simply drops the entire file without comment and does not even include the file in its list of scripts. Syntax errors should be the easiest to detect and correct, but I am reduced to falling back to an older script and step-by-step adding code until the script fails to load, thus pointing me to the offending code. With every review of FireBug raving over its debugging power, I know I must be doing something wrong, but what?
Th

Answer (score 0):

- Can you create some minimalistic code that is giving you that behavior?
- How do you include the external scripts, using `<script src=".."></script>`, or load it with XHR?
- What version of Firefox / Firebug?

It's true that Firebug doesn't display the broken scripts in the Script panel, but still, in both cases (script tag include / XHR & eval), you should get a message in Console panel with the syntax error.

Do you have `Console > Show JavaScript Errors` checked?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response jakub.g:
In response to your comments:

Comment: Thanks for the response jakub.g:
In response to your comments: (1) I tried making a simple case [link](http://questrak.com/test/test.html), and it did as you mentioned, reporting an error and not including the broken script. I need to try to reconstruct the failure to find why my working script does not report the syntax error. (2) I include the script with a <script> tag. (3) Firefox 12.0, Firebug 1.9.2